# How to especify stronger priors in MCMCglmm?

Tags: r, mcmc

I have been working for weeks with the MCMCglmm R package. It's the first time I work with it. I have read a lot of papers and guides for a better understanding but I can't solve the problem that I have:

That's a piece of my data (just for one individual):

```
Species Individual  Lineage Prevalence  day breeding    Year    phylo   
Aegithalos_caudatus I1  SGS1    0   125 Yes i2010   Aegithalos_caudatus   
Aegithalos_caudatus I1  CARDUEL1    0   125 Yes i2010   Aegithalos_caudatus 
Aegithalos_caudatus I1  CARDUEL2    0   125 Yes i2010   Aegithalos_caudatus 
Aegithalos_caudatus I1  CARDUEL3    0   125 Yes i2010   Aegithalos_caudatus 
Aegithalos_caudatus I1  DELURB1 0   125 Yes i2010   Aegithalos_caudatus 
Aegithalos_caudatus I1  DELURB2 0   125 Yes i2010   Aegithalos_caudatus 
Aegithalos_caudatus I1  DELURB3 0   125 Yes i2010   Aegithalos_caudatus 
Aegithalos_caudatus I1  DELURB5 0   125 Yes i2010   Aegithalos_caudatus 
Aegithalos_caudatus I1  DURB6   0   125 Yes i2010   Aegithalos_caudatus 
Aegithalos_caudatus I1  GRW2    0   125 Yes i2010   Aegithalos_caudatus 
Aegithalos_caudatus I1  GRW4    0   125 Yes i2010   Aegithalos_caudatus 
Aegithalos_caudatus I1  GRW9    0   125 Yes i2010   Aegithalos_caudatus 
Aegithalos_caudatus I1  RTSR1   0   125 Yes i2010   Aegithalos_caudatus 
Aegithalos_caudatus I1  ROBIN1  0   125 Yes i2010   Aegithalos_caudatus 
Aegithalos_caudatus I1  GRW9    0   125 Yes i2010   Aegithalos_caudatus 
Aegithalos_caudatus I1  HIPOL1  0   125 Yes i2010   Aegithalos_caudatus 
Aegithalos_caudatus I1  COLL1   0   125 Yes i2010   Aegithalos_caudatus 
Aegithalos_caudatus I1  GRW11   0   125 Yes i2010   Aegithalos_caudatus 
Aegithalos_caudatus I1  PADOM_5 0   125 Yes i2010   Aegithalos_caudatus 
Aegithalos_caudatus I1  PADOM01 0   125 Yes i2010   Aegithalos_caudatus 
Aegithalos_caudatus I1  PADOM08 0   125 Yes i2010   Aegithalos_caudatus 
Aegithalos_caudatus I1  PADOM22 0   125 Yes i2010   Aegithalos_caudatus 
Aegithalos_caudatus I1  PAHIS_01    0   125 Yes i2010   Aegithalos_caudatus 
Aegithalos_caudatus I1  CCF2    0   125 Yes i2010   Aegithalos_caudatus 
Aegithalos_caudatus I1  SYMEL1  0   125 Yes i2010   Aegithalos_caudatus 
Aegithalos_caudatus I1  SYAT_05 0   125 Yes i2010   Aegithalos_caudatus 
Aegithalos_caudatus I1  TURDUS3 0   125 Yes i2010
```

I have 815 individuals that belongs to 23 different species. Each individual have 24 entries (one per parasite linage). 
I have also want to take into account the phylogenetic host (bird) tree.
The main objective of my analyses is to test if the prevalence (infected=0 or not infected=1) may be affected by host species or by lineages.

So, I run my MCMCglmm model and I get an error messages about my priors:

```
 data= read.table("data.txt", header = T)
 phylo<-read.nexus("tree.nex")
 inv.phylo<-inverseA(phylo,nodes="TIPS",scale=TRUE)
 prior.ex.<- list(G = list(G1 = list(V = 1, nu = 2, alpha.mu = 0, alpha.V = 10000),
                                     G2 = list(V = 1, nu = 2, alpha.mu = 0, alpha.V = 10000),
                                     G3 = list(V = 1, nu = 2, alpha.mu = 0, alpha.V = 10000),
                                     G4 = list(V = 1, nu = 2, alpha.mu = 0, alpha.V = 10000),
                                     R = list(R1 = list(V =1, nu = 0.02, fix = TRUE),
                                                  R2 = list(V =1, nu = 0.02, fix = TRUE))))
 model <- MCMCglmm(fixed = Prevalence ~ day + breeding, 
                    random =  ~ Year + Lineage + Individual + Individual:Species, 
                    data = data,
                    family = "categorical",  ginverse=list(phylo=inv.phyl$Ainv), nitt=300000, burnin=60000, thin=200, verbose = TRUE)

                           # MCMC iteration = 0

     # Acceptance ratio for liability set 1 = 0.000658

                           # MCMC iteration = 1000

     # Acceptance ratio for liability set 1 = 0.443318

                           # MCMC iteration = 2000

     # Acceptance ratio for liability set 1 = 0.428678

                           # MCMC iteration = 3000

     # Acceptance ratio for liability set 1 = 0.438693

                           # MCMC iteration = 4000

     # Acceptance ratio for liability set 1 = 0.437736

                           # MCMC iteration = 5000

     # Acceptance ratio for liability set 1 = 0.440917

                           # MCMC iteration = 6000

     # Acceptance ratio for liability set 1 = 0.430484

                           # MCMC iteration = 7000

     # Acceptance ratio for liability set 1 = 0.434346

                           # MCMC iteration = 8000

     # Acceptance ratio for liability set 1 = 0.428129

                           # MCMC iteration = 9000

     # Acceptance ratio for liability set 1 = 0.435863

                           # MCMC iteration = 10000

     # Acceptance ratio for liability set 1 = 0.437513

                           # MCMC iteration = 11000

     # Acceptance ratio for liability set 1 = 0.437331

                           # MCMC iteration = 12000

     # Acceptance ratio for liability set 1 = 0.431787

                           # MCMC iteration = 13000

     # Acceptance ratio for liability set 1 = 0.429239

                           # MCMC iteration = 14000

     # Acceptance ratio for liability set 1 = 0.435133

                           # MCMC iteration = 15000

     # Acceptance ratio for liability set 1 = 0.436029
    # Error in MCMCglmm(fixed = Prevalence ~ day + breeding, random = ~Year +  : 
      # Mixed model equations singular: use a (stronger) prior
```

I have tried to change burnin, nitt and thin but at the end it always says the same error. However, if I decrease this values I don't get any error but my plots are not as they should be.

Comment: Is this your code? Every line seems to follow a different convention, which makes it look like you've borrowed it in part from someone. Maybe that someone else can help you? Failing that, surely there's someone at the institute that can give you a hand. This seems like a pretty involved research question and it would be hard for someone without specific insight to help.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, in the model specification You've missed to set 'prior' to be your prior list, so Your model specification should look like:

```
model <- MCMCglmm(fixed = Prevalence ~ day + breeding, 
                random =  ~ Year + Lineage + Individual + Individual:Species, 
                prior=prior.ex, data = data,
                family = "categorical",  ginverse=list(phylo=inv.phyl$Ainv), nitt=300000, burnin=60000, thin=200, verbose = TRUE)
```

Also, I think Your prior isn't fully operational, try this one:

```
prior.ex<- list(G = list(G1 = list(V = 1, nu = 2, alpha.mu = 0, alpha.V = 10000),
                      G2 = list(V = 1, nu = 2, alpha.mu = 0, alpha.V = 10000),
                      G3 = list(V = 1, nu = 2, alpha.mu = 0, alpha.V = 10000),
                      G4 = list(V = 1, nu = 2, alpha.mu = 0, alpha.V = 10000)),
                      R = list(V=1, fix=1))
```

I hope this helps!